# Error message: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-community

I am trying to build project on android but I am getting this error. What should be the possible solution for this problem.
**Error message**: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object.
**Error**: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.